# Android-It takes 2-4 clicks to finish Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, activity-finish

I've a fragment, when I drag an imageview to edge of screen, I want to open an activity, this is done, however when I click on a back button in my activity to finish it, it takes me 2-4 clicks to dismiss it, I don't know why, Any ideas?
Here's my code in my fragment:

```
    private void goToDodgeScreen(){
    Intent dodge=new Intent(getActivity(),Dodge.class);
    Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(),android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle();
    startActivity(dodge,bundle);
}
```

Here's my code in the activity:

```
    private void onTouchListeners(){
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you print a log every time the activity gets created.  To make sure it isn't starting several activities.  Also a log when pressing the back button.  In order to be sure it is registering the clicks.

Comment: Hey, where did you register that onTouch listner, and can you share us some more code